# VBA Gantt Chart, Parent-activities dictionary

Tags: excel, vba, gantt-chart

I am brand new to VBA and would need your help on a personal project.
I want to create a custom Gantt chart on Excel VBA.
Excel version is Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2208 Build 16.0.15601.20446) 64-bit

One aspect of the project I am struggling with is to manage "Parent-activities". Lets say that I have an activity identified as "Child", that can not start before other activities identified as "Parents" finish.
I would like to build a Public dictionary, each entry/key being a "Child", each child having a collection of "Parents".

My issue is that my code is very buggy, sometimes it works, sometimes not and I can not tell why...

Here is what I tried. I would really appreciate if you could flag any issue.
The Parent List is buggy (sometimes works, sometimes not).
The Parent Count function does not work, I  guess I dont have the right syntax.

```
Public Parents_Dict As New Scripting.Dictionary 'I want this dictionary accessible from any Sub and I want to keep its content throughout the project
Public Child As Variant 'This will store the ID of the Child depending on the context
Public Parent As Variant 'This will store the ID of the Parent depending on context

'I have a button "Manage Parent" that triggers a user form and save the Child ID
Sub Open_Parents_Manager() 'We want to open the user form to manage parent activities
'We find the activity ID of the cell that was active when we opened the form
'We store this ID as the Variable "Child" that is recognize in this whole module
Child = CStr(ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1).Value)
Manage_Parents.Show vbModeless 'VbModeless allow to interact with the speadsheet while the user form is still open
End Sub


'In this user form I have a Listbox that should list the Parents of the selected Child
Sub UserForm_Activate()
'We want the title of the box to mention Child ID to help the user confirm they are working on the right activity
Me.Caption = "Manage parent activities of " & Child 'Mention the ID of the Child as a title of the window
'We want to display the list of the current parents of this activity
Call Display_Parents_List
'We want to display the number of parents of this activity
Call Count_Parents
End Sub

Sub Display_Parents_List()
UserForm.Parents_ListBox.Clear
Dim Val As Variant 
On Error Resume Next 'Override error if no dictionary exists
For Each Val In Parents_Dict(Child)
UserForm.Parents_ListBox.AddItem Val 'We add each item in the collection in our ListBox
Next Val
End Sub

'In this user form I also have a label that should return the number of parents for the selected child
Sub Count_Parents() 'We inform the user of how many parents this Child has
If Parents_Dict.Exists(Child) Then
UserForm.Label1.Caption = Parents_Dict(Child).Count 'This one does not work
Else
UserForm.Label1.Caption = "Currently, this activity has no parent"
End If
End Sub

'Finally I have button to add parents.
Sub Add_Parent()
Parent = "TP9" 'for testing I change the values manually here

If Parents_Dict.Exists(Child) Then
    On Error Resume Next
    Parents_Dict(Child).Add Item:=Parent, Key:=Parent 'Collection can have multiple times the same item but not under the same Key, Using Parent as Item & Key avoids duplicates
    On Error GoTo 0
Else
    Dim newList As Collection
    Set newList = New Collection
    newList.Add Item:=Parent, Key:=Parent
    Parents_Dict.Add Key:=Child, Item:=newList
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: @FaneDurub, Parents_Dict(Child).Count make sense as each member of parents_dic is a collection.

Comment: @wrbp Yes, you are right. I was not attentive enough. I deleted my comments...

Comment: An observation, you should use "permanent memory" to do this (a table in the worksheet of something), unless you pan to save that dictionary and collections to the sheet at some point. Why use a collection instead of another dictionary as the element of the main dictionary?

Comment: @wrbp, You are spot on. Thanks for your useful comment.

Comment: 1. After precising the modules of the subroutines i was calling and declaring Parent and Child variables as public the code is running smoothly. So I assure you @FaneDurub, with my few hours of experience sure the code is probably not very elegant but it means something

Comment: 2. @wrbp Do you mean it would be better to have a dictionnary of dictionnaries rather a dictionary of collection? Could you explain me a bit more of the advantage in that?

Comment: 3. @wrbp yes I realized yesterday that the dictionary is not saved when the workbook is closed. I am thinking of dedicating a hidden sheet to "print" the dictionary. Issue is I would like to make the software as user friendly as possible so that other people who are not savvy at excel could utilize it seamlessly. Ideal would be to automatically load the dictionary when opening the workbook and automatically saving it when closing the workbook. I will have to explore a bit more.